# How to detect which process accesses a file?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, process, monitoring

I'm trying to reword [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/monitoring-file-changes-process-access-to-files) question: Is it possible to monitor *which process* accesses a given file/directory (on a Linux system)?

Background: on a regular basis I'm detecting file access to a certain file using inotify, but I don't know anything else and need to know which process to kill.

My naive approach would be to run `strace` on suspicious processes, but this is not very reproducible and easy to automate.

I tried to install `gamin` as stated in the linked question but this package does not provide any executable files like e.g. inotify and the "[documentation](https://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/using.html)" is *very* sparse.

Comment: [`auditd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99091/108618)?

Comment: you could look into https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework